# MySQL-How to achieve a table odd increase one table even increase

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have two tables, one is named user1, and one is named user2.

I want the id of table user1 union table user2 is unique.

So I plan to make the ID of a table odd and the ID of the other even.

How do I achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto increment by 2 for a particular table in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373582/how-to-auto-increment-by-2-for-a-particular-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see, it can't be achieved by `auto-increment` in my situation.

quote from [mysql-auto-increasement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment):

> the next value inserted is the least value in the series that is greater than the maximum existing value in the AUTO_INCREMENT column. The series is calculated like this:
>   `auto_increment_offset + N × auto_increment_increment`

At last, I control the `primary key(id)` in my code instead of using `auto-increment`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` to divide the values into two tables.Hope this following link will be help you..

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment